# `Identified By Password` in Create Database MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

I reviewed the logs records for create database-user and it caught my attention: `'*94060046C2F3321FA041154DF7FE002629402435'`

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*94060046C2F3321FA041154DF7FE002629402435';
```

What is this password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MySQL hashes passwords stored in the mysql.user table to obfuscate
>   them. For most statements described here, MySQL automatically hashes
>   the password specified.

So '*94060046C2F3321FA041154DF7FE002629402435'; is the obfuscated value of the password

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/assigning-passwords.html

Comment: So, this is my MySQL root password encrypted version? Can I print this password on the screen with PHP?

Comment: This  should be your passord encripted ..you can check  you user table using SELECT * FROM mysql.user;  and you have these values ..  and  you can retrieve this value and print in php.  but this is another question .. hope my answer is useful .. at least

Comment: Is not a php encyiption  ... this is performed by mysql ..  and you should eval mysql encryption and compare with php  so you in php can obtain the string .. but for encyption .. ...  ... is another question ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627695/how-can-i-encrypt-the-password-with-php-mysql

Comment: Is `PASSWORD` still valid syntax in latest MySQL versions?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt  you can easly check at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assigning-passwords.html