# How can I encrypt the password with PHP? - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I can create a database with this query

```
$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
             CREATE USER '$user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
             GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*3D3B92F242033365AE5BC6A8E6FC3E1679F4140A';
             GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `$username\_$dbusername`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';")
```

But encrypted passwords are contained in the query:

```
'*3D3B92F242033365AE5BC6A8E6FC3E1679F4140A'
```

decryption version:

```
test1234
```

This automatically encrypted by MySQL and how can I encrypt the `test1234` with PHP?

Full Version

```
$user='abc_dbuser';
$db="abc_dbname";
$pass='test1234';
$dbusername="dbname";
$username=get_current_user();

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);
        $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
                    CREATE USER '$user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';

                    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '$db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*3D3B92F242033365AE5BC6A8E6FC3E1679F4140A';
                    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `$username\_$dbusername`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';
                    ") 
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));
```

[my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626626/identified-by-password-in-create-database-mysql/)

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph This question is about how MySQL hashes passwords internally for use in authenticating its clients. It's not about creating your own user database.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I understand that. But should we ignore good security just because MySQL has a password hash capability? Have no concern about the security for the users?

Comment: @zaph I'm not sure what you mean. You don't have a choice over how MySQL hashes passwords.

Comment: Just don't use that functionality, it is not secure. For PHP there is `password_hash` and `password_verify` that are secure. Sure, a few more lines of code, that is a small cost to pay for user security. Shouldn't we help developers to use secure methods?

Comment: @zaph We're talking about the password used in `new PDO(DSN, $user, $password)`. How would you use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` in place of that?

Comment: If there is no secure way to use PDO then it should not be used.